# Obtain the frequency response of a time domain chirp signal

Tags: frequency-response, time-frequency, spectrogram

I have simulation data in the time domain and I need to represent them in the frequency domain.

The data have been obtained time integrating the following equation:

$m \ddot{x} + c\dot{x} + kx = A \sin{(\phi(t))}$

where $\sin{(\phi(t))}$ represents a logarithmic chirp. Therefore, since also the integrated time histories are chirps, I cannot use the FFT to transform them in the frequency-domain, but I have to do something like it was done in this answer: [system response: time vs frequency. Why do I get different magnitudes?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19779/system-response-time-vs-frequency-why-do-i-get-different-magnitudes/19851#19851)

Therefore I used the spectrogram in this way:

```
% Resample at a constant sampling frequency
dt = 0.0001;
t0 = time(1);
tend = time(end);
new_t = t0:dt:tend;
Fs = 1/dt;

acce_TS = timeseries(acce_cog,time);
acce_res = resample(acce_TS,new_t);

% Spectrogram
win = hamming(256);
noverlap = 0;
nfft = 512;
X = abs(spectrogram(acce_res.data, win, noverlap, nfft,Fs));
X = 2*X/sum(win);
surf(X)
```

And here come the problems:

1) On the time axis I have wrong values: the time history lasts $49.5 \ s$ whereas in the spectrogram plot I see values from 0 to 2000

2) The peak response should be at nearly $30 Hz$ (which is the resonance frequency of the system, given as $f_n = \sqrt{k/m}$), whereas from the spectrogarm I see it at nearly $5 Hz$

3) The amplitude of the peak of the spectrogram is a bit higher than in the time history

4) I actually need to see only the frequency-amplitude plot, not the 3D representation, so how can I do that? At the moment I am using `view([90 0])`, but is there a way to plot directly the 2D plot?

**EDIT**: Here the plots

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can use contourf to view a flattened 2D image

Comment: Check your time and frequency data using Parseval's theorem

Comment: The `contourf` gives the xy plot and the colormap refers to the z right? So, if I am not mistaken, in my case I will have the time-frequency plot and the colormap will give the amplitude. But what I need is the yz plot, so frequency-amplitude

Comment: I tried the check fro Parseval's theorem, therefore I computed: `Et = norm(acce_res.data).^2` which gives `2.3430e+7` and `Ef = nrom(X).^2` (before dividing it by `sum(win)`) and it gives `2.6687e+009`. So something is wrong

Comment: Hmm, why norm? You need to sum energy

Comment: Actually I never did this before, therefore I had a look here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/242155 and it uses the `norm` (second post)

Comment: Good point but the example divides by N, not the sum of the array A=fft(a); norm(A(:)).^2/numel(A)

Comment: Trying with `sum(abs(acce_res.data).^2)` gives the same result `2.3430e+007` for the time history but a slightly different result for the other, infact `sum(abs(X(:)).^2)` gives `2.8187e+009`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) On the time axis I have wrong values: the time history lasts 45 s whereas in the spectrogram plot I see values from 0 to 2000

[RTFM on `surf`.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html)  You'll need to do something like `surf(new_t,new_f,X)` instead of just `surf(X)`.  Your `new_f` should be something like

```
new_f = linspace(0,Fs/2,256);
```

NOTE: I don't have access to matlab, and am not sure of the orientation of `X`. You may have to swap the parameter locations of `new_t` and `new_f` on `surf`.

> 4) I actually need to see only the frequency-amplitude plot, not the 3D representation, so how can I do that? At the moment I am using view([90 0]), but is there a way to plot directly the 2D plot?

Do something like:

```
plot(new_t, max(X));
```

You may have to do `max(X')` instead, depending on the orientation of `X`.

I'll need to think about answers to 2 & 3. Watch this space.

Comment: I tried plotting `surf(new_t,new_f,X)` but the dimensions do not match: `X` is `257x1951` whereas `new_t` is `1x499540` and `new_f` is `1x257`, so the problem is `new_t`. The suggestion about the 2D plot works perfectly :)

Comment: I just noted that `499540/256 = 1951` so I think the problem with the dimensions comes from the windowing

Answer (score 0):

Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7enfnY_c6Pk&t=34s) for detail explanation-->
Frequency Response of Chirp Signal -Eye of Sauron(The Lord of the Rings)